# Getting error on cloudwatch event rules on glue job state change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I have created cloudwatch event rule for glue job state change. I am getting notifications correctly for all glue job state change. But i need to send notifications for some particular glue jobs. i tried with adding multiple jobs but not working properly.

glue jobs:

```
glue_job1
glue_job2
glue_job3
```

event rule: with this rule i can get notifications for all jobs.

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.glue"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Glue Job State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "FAILED",
      "TIMEOUT",
      "SUCCEEDED"
    ]
  }
}
```

event rule2: with this i am not getting proper notifications

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.glue"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Glue Job State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "FAILED",
      "TIMEOUT",
      "SUCCEEDED"
    ],
    "jobName": [
      "glue_job1",
      "glue_job2",
      "glue_job3"
    ]
  }
}
```

how can we send notifications for only specific glue jobs ? how can we create event rule for this scenario. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For me, this rule did not work when I had it in CloudWatch. I had to recreate the rule in EventBridge, specifically using the "default" event bus.

I am not sure why the same rule didn't work in CloudWatch or even in EventBridge with a custom event bus, but it is working properly now.